# help with an error was encountered

Tags: error

we are using expression engine and recently found that after creating a user that we can no longer log into the admin, when logging in we get the following: An error was encountered, unable to load the requested class: services_json. EE version 292, using Zoo Flexible Admin.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling add-ons in the config.php file. And try login again. The problem come from Zoo visitor add-on.